# Arrange side by side or detach Inspector or/and (Web) Console in/from Firefox's (v71) Developer Tools

Tags: user-interface, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, web-console

*Inspector* and *(Web) Console* are the tabs I (and perhaps others, too) use most. So, it'd be convenient to arrange them:

- side by side in the Dev Tools
- detached from the FF Window on a second monitor

I didn't find any option in the according menus to achieve this. Can this be done yet with some tweak/hack?

Comment: Well, detached is easy, there's an option in the DevTools extra menu to have the DevTools in a separate window. Having them split vertically can be done by just hitting "ESC" when viewing the inspector. Horizontal orientation is possible, but doesn't appear to be easy.

Comment: @Makyen Detaching the (entire) Dev Tools isn't what I meant. I meant just one of the tabs/windows of the Dev Tools (as it can be done with any window in Eclipse, for instance). Splitting vertically isn't ideal since modern widescreen monitors are...well...wide.

Comment: Detaching one of the DevTools tabs into it's own window is beyond what's possible without significant modifications to Firefox. It would be possible with an old style extension. It might be possible with a WebExtensions Experiment, but I really haven't played around with those. However, from what I've seen, they have the required access. Just switching to horizontal layout is moderately easy, and can be done from the Browser Toolbox on individual DevTool instances. Having it apply to all DevTools would require minor mods to Firefox HTML/XUL, or the above extension types.

Comment: I don't see any usecase or benefit? there some tabs which could be hidden, and you can re-order tabs, put most used tabs at the beginning.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani The fact that you do not see any use case doesn't mean that there is none for others. I said: "_the tabs I use most_". Arranging them side-by-side would be convenient when developing/debugging a user script that changes the DOM, for instance.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica yes, there is one way per user to deal with any subject, but the point is, is specific way good enough to spend time to add it? yes, I like to put every tab every where I want, but is it not really useful thing for others?. this is what I meant by_I don't see any usecase or benefit_. anyway if you like to this feature, you should file an issue on [bugzilla.mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). maybe they add it for you.